# How to build a search form in rails for soundcloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i'm new to rails and trying to figure out how to build a search for to get info back from Soundcloud.

If i build everything static then i get back the info but i cannot get it to work with a search form

Method in Controller:

```
      def search
        @client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => ENV["SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID"])
      end
```

THIS WORKS

```
#search.html.erb

<div class="form">
<% @client.get('/tracks', :q => 'djsneak'  ).each do |track| %>
<ul>
    <li><%= track.title %></li>
    <li><%= image_tag  track.artwork_url %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
</div>
```

What i would like to use:

```
<!--search.html.erb-->

<div class="form">
  <%= form_tag("soundcloud_search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div>  
 <h3>results</h3>    
  <ul>
    <li><%= track.title %></li>
    <li><%= image_tag  track.artwork_url %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it myself, but for who is interested:

```
<!--search.html.erb-->

<!--search form-->
<div class="form">
 <%= form_tag("searchit", method: "get") do %>
 <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
 <%= text_field_tag(:q, params[:q]) %>
 <%= submit_tag("Search", :name => nil) %>
 <% end %>
</div>

<!--Results-->

<div class="form">
Search Results

<% @client.get('/tracks', :q => params[:q]  ).each do |track| %>
  <ul>
      <li><%= track.title %></li>
      <li><%= image_tag  track.artwork_url %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
</div>
```